# Upate table with AJAX in Laravel 5.3 not working

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I trying to use an AJAX PUT request to update a row in my database and I am trying to send the request to my controller. This is my AJAX call:

```
$('#edit-trucks').on('click',function(){

    var truckNo = $('#XA').val();
    var truckOwner = $('#truck-owner').val();
    var vehicle_number = $('#vehicle-number').val();
    var capacity = $('#capacity').val();
    var end_of_insurance = $('#end-of-insurance').val();
    var end_of_kteo = $('#end-of-KTEO').val();
    var truckCode = $('#truck-code').val();
    var leased = $('#leased').val();
    var truckModel = $('#truck-model').val(); 

    $.ajax({
        url: 'editTruck',
        type: 'put',           
        data: {
            truckNo: truckNo,
            truckOwner: truckOwner,
            vehicle_number: vehicle_number,
            capacity: capacity,
            end_of_insurance: end_of_insurance,
            end_of_kteo: end_of_kteo,
            truckCode: truckCode,
            leased: leased,
            truckModel: truckModel
          },
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },           
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(){
            console.log('success');
        },            
        error: function(){
           console.log('something went wrong');
        }         
    });
});
```

So far so good. If I console.log() my data is seems I can get them from the form. I am using Laravel Collective for the form:

```
 {!!Form::open(array('action' => ['Trucks@editTruck'], 'method' => 'put')) !!}
```

and my route is the following:

```
Route::put('/editTruck', 'Trucks@editTruck',function(){ });
```

Now I am using Request $request in the parameters of the controller but somehow it looks like I cannot get the incoming values. For example the following var_dump will say NULL.

```
public function editTruck(Request $request)
{              
      $data = $request->input('truckNo');
      var_dump($data);
}
```

Same happens if I use

```
$data = $request->truckNo;
```

instead. So I am wondering how can I get the values that are been sent to my controller with my AJAX call? Why am I getting `NULL` values?

What I was planning to do is:

```
 public function editTruck(Request $request)
{
       $singleTruck = Truck::find($request->truckNo);          
       $singleTruck->truckNo = $request->input('truckNo'); 
       $singleTruck->truckOwner = $request->input('truckOwner');
       ........
       $singleTruck->save();
}
```

Comment: what is the exact error you are looking. Chack your console error

Comment: can you try dd(request()->all()) - to check what come from front end?

Comment: @DenisGorgul $request->all() returns a null array like []

Comment: well, how are you checking that? Are you sure that after you click the '#edit-trucks' button your request reaches the controller? Can you check the Network tab in the browser dev tools to see the server response?

Comment: have you set the csrf token in meta tag?

Comment: @DenisGorgul When I click the button I see the 'eidtTruck' rout been loaded in the Network tab. I do  return $request->all();  in the controller is still an empty array []

Comment: can you change the form method to 'post' to check if it helps? Of course everywhere (ajax, Form::open, route)

Comment: @DenisGorgul tried that already... :( still the same.  Gurpal yes.. I include it my main layout  <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

Comment: can you check your web browser console network tab after clicking the button? try to find which response is getting by controller and check the url is perfect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found it. Looks like the AJAX was malformed. So here is how it should be written:

```
  $('#edit-trucks').on('click',function(){

    var truckNo = $('#XA').val();
    var truckOwner = $('#truck-owner').val();
    var vehicle_number = $('#vehicle-number').val();
    var capacity = $('#vehicle_capacity').val();
    var end_of_insurance = $('#end-of-insurance').val();
    var end_of_kteo = $('#end-of-KTEO').val();
    var truckCode = $('#truck-code').val();
    var leased = $('#leasing').val();
    var truckModel = $('#truck-model').val();


    var outGoingData = {
            'truckNo': truckNo,
            'truckOwner': truckOwner,
            'vehicle_number': vehicle_number,
            'capacity': capacity,
            'end_of_insurance': end_of_insurance,
            'end_of_kteo': end_of_kteo,
            'truckCode': truckCode,
            'leased': leased,
            'truckModel': truckModel,
          };

    var data = JSON.stringify(outGoingData);


    $.ajax({
        url: 'editTruck',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,            <!-- The error was here. It was data: {data}-->
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },           
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'JSON',            
        success: function(response){
            alert("The data should be "+ response);
        },            
        error: function(){
            console.log('skata');
        }         
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer here:

https://laravel.io/forum/02-13-2014-i-can-not-get-inputs-from-a-putpatch-request

You should change your form method and method inside your js code to "post", and add extra field "_method" = "PUT"

probably it can help.

Comment: hhhmmm.... Changed my AJAX type to POST, route to POST and form method to POST but I added  {!! Form::hidden('_method', 'PUT') !!} inside my form. But still nothing. If I return $request->all() in the editTruck function it returns an empty array []. It must be something simple that I am missing..  :(